# Using MODEL clause in Oracle and returning previous values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that should return V * previous C when MOD (rn, 2)! = 0,
and should return V / previous C when MOD (rn, 2) = 0 (for each row sorted by rn).

```
select *  
FROM (
       Select 1 rn, 1 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 2 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 3 rn, 4 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 4 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 5 rn, 3 V from dual  

)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES ( V, 0 c)
  RULES (
   c[MOD(rn, 2) != 0] = nvl(c[cv()-1],1)*V[cv()]
  ,c[MOD(rn, 2) = 0] = c[cv()-1] /V[cv()]
  -- c[any] = nvl(c[cv()-1],1) *B_VOL[cv()]
  ) order by 1;
```

This is example of valid output:

| ROWNUM | V | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |

But my query return this (incorrect output):

| ROWNUM | V | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |

Please, help me fix my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the `MOD`ulo filter in a `CASE` expression on the right-hand side of the assignment rather than trying to have odd- and even-row rules:

```sql
select *  
FROM (
       SELECT 1 rn, 1 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 2 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 3 rn, 4 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 4 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 5 rn, 3 V from dual  
)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES ( V, 0 AS c)
  RULES (
    c[1] = V[1],
    c[rn>1] = CASE MOD(cv(rn), 2)
              WHEN 0
              THEN c[cv()-1] / V[cv()]
              ELSE c[cv()-1] * V[cv()]
              END
)
order by rn;
```

Which outputs:

> | RN | V | C |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 | .5 |
> | 3 | 4 | 2 |
> | 4 | 2 | 1 |
> | 5 | 3 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=267bfcecaf43ce16974f7a085db7dea5)*

---

## Update

Your query works if you use `AUTOMATIC ORDER` (rather than the default `SEQUENTIAL ORDER`):

```sql
select *  
FROM (
       Select 1 rn, 1 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 2 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 3 rn, 4 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 4 rn, 2 V from dual  UNION ALL
       Select 5 rn, 3 V from dual  

)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES ( V, 0 c)
  RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
   c[MOD(rn, 2) != 0] = nvl(c[cv(rn)-1],1)*V[cv(rn)]
  ,c[MOD(rn, 2) = 0] = c[cv(rn)-1] /V[cv(rn)]
  )
order by 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53a93abd9313b7d7d9fc46399ffa5a22)*

Comment: It is worth to say that the original result looks like that because rules are evaluated independently and for all the dataset, not the first rule for rn = N -> the second rule for rn = N -> the first rule for rn = N + 1 -> etc.

Comment: Where can I set the sort order for the clause "AUTOMATIC ORDER"?

Comment: @JenjaO I am not sure I understand your question. For `AUTOMATIC ORDER`, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) states "When you specify `AUTOMATIC ORDER`, the database evaluates the rules based on their dependency order. In this case, a cell can be assigned a value once only." so you don't specify an order, it is worked out automatically. For the `SELECT`, you use the `ORDER BY` clause at the end (exactly as you did).

Comment: @JenjaO Do you mean something like this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c4ffb72350e7beb470514dfc198e74c)?